Database is not creating for Image Target” Vuforia
I am using vuforia for image Target in unity . but i have an issue that i am unable to create databse for image target - Steps which i have used to achieve this :

Step 1: Go to Target Managet in developer portal
Step 2: Click on Generate Database
Step 3: Fill the name of Database and select "device" as type click on Generate
Step 4:Click on Created Database then click on Add Target
Step 5: Select Image and after that select width and give name

But after that i have not got any option like Submit or Add that's why i am unable to move further I have also uploaded image from where you can see issue .

I have searched everywhere but not got any solution please

Hi, from the image, it looks like the window is cut. The buttons should be just below your windows bar. Try CTRL + - to zoom out in your browser

wow your screen is very tiny - and yeah they ought to design a responsive form already but still using old 2010 interface!
